Defining macro and using data types to find an absolute value
I'm trying to solve this problem from my textbook in the Preprocessor section.
The problem asks to define a macro ABSOLUTE(num) to calculate an absolute value of some number or arithmetic expression.
I resolved it by including <stdlib> and defining a function with abs(num):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ABSOLUTE(num) printf("The absolute value of %i is %i\n", (num), abs(num))

int main()
{
    ABSOLUTE(-1);
    ABSOLUTE(3-4);
    ABSOLUTE(7);
    ABSOLUTE(-8-3);

    return 0;
}

But before I was trying to manipulate data types, because the book section was reviewing them and said nothing about the  library. However, it didn't work quite obviously.
#include <stdio.h>
#define ABSOLUTE(num) printf("The absolute value of %i is %u\n", (num), (num))

int main()
{
    ABSOLUTE(-1);
    ABSOLUTE(3-4);
    ABSOLUTE(7);
    ABSOLUTE(-8-3);

    return 0;
}

I understand the mistake here, but wonder if that's even possible to solve this problem by manipulating data types or other preprocessor directives.

To compute the absolute value, simply negate the value if it is negative:
#define ABSOLUTE(x) ((x) < 0 ? -(x) : (x))
This will work with any type for which the unary - operator is defined (subject to overflow), which is nicer than using abs since abs requires int.

Might be worth mentioning the dangers of using expressions with side effects e.g. int i = -5 ; int j = ABSOLUTE(--i); What is the value of j?

I was kind of trying to do that with #if directory, but that resulted in redefining the same macro and didn't give the desired result. I was not yet aware of application of ? and : operators.

@SofiaZaiafarova what will be the result of int y = 3; int z = ABSOLUTE(y++);

@JeremyP I don't quite understand. Wouldn't that just make the value move further from zero? Meaning that -- decreases a value, and if i is already negative, it would make it even "more negative" and, as consequence, make j "more positive"?

@0___________ z = 3 and y = 4?

@SofiaZaiafarova no, it is undefined. Macros are very dangerous and should be avoided as a plaque.

@0___________: It is not undefined; there is a sequence point in the conditional operator.

@EricPostpischil ok - but it will not be the result expected by Sofia

@SofiaZaiafarova If you see ABSOLUTE(--i) you might think, it pre decrements i and then takes the absolute value. So, if i is -5 you would expect the answer to be 6, but it isn't in this implementation: it is 7 because the parameter of the macro is used twice. i.e. --i is evaluated twice.

Do not use macros as you can get into the grey area, use functions instead.
int ABSOLUTE(int x)
{
    if(x == INT_MIN)
    {
        x = -1;
    }
    else if(x < 0) x = -x;
    
    return x;
}

void printABSOLUTE(int x)
{
    int result = ABSOLUTE(x);
    if(result < 0)
    {
        printf("Integer overflow\n");
    }
    else printf("ABSOLUTE(%d) = %d\n", x, result);
}
 
int main()
{
    printABSOLUTE(-1);
    printABSOLUTE(1);
    printABSOLUTE(0);
    printABSOLUTE(INT_MAX);
    printABSOLUTE(INT_MIN);
}

